# Why doesn't display:none property work on <li> elements?

Tags: html, css

i have a problem with html/css.
I am trying to make a drop down menu that extends on mouseover and colapses on mouseout. But li elements ignore hide (display none) class.

My html part:

```
  <ul id="dropDownBar" class="hideList">
     <li id="preschool" class="hide">Pradine</li>
     <li id="middleschool" class="hide">Pagrindine</li>
     <li id="highschool" class="hide">Abiturientai</li>
     <li id="grownups" class="hide">Suauge</li>
     <li id="conferences" class="hide">Konferencijos</li>
     <li id="other" class="hide">Teminiai</li>
  </ul><!--end of dropDownBar-->
```

in css there are hideList and showList classes that change height of dropDownBar from 0 to the height of the extended menu with transition effect. So that seems to work fine.
But on top i want to make it that li elements appear and disappear as dropDownBar is extending and colapsing.

So li element initialy should be invisible and appear after mouseover on dropDownBar.

.hide class only has display:none. Yet all li elements are visible all the time even thought dropDownBar is extending and colapsing as it should.

Ps.I'm using Javascript (no libraries) to toggle classes on mouseover/mouseout events.

Why doesn't this work?

Thanks.

Comment: You will need to post the rest of your code. CSS and JS

Comment: li elements do not ignore display property. My guess is somewhere around other parts of your CSS clashes with the display property.

Answer (score 2):

`display: none` works for `li` elements and hides those having that class, so the problem has to be elsewhere:

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul id="dropDownBar" class="hideList">
  <li id="preschool">Pradine</li>
  <li id="middleschool">Pagrindine</li>
  <li id="highschool" class="hide">Abiturientai</li>
  <li id="grownups" class="hide">Suauge</li>
  <li id="conferences" class="hide">Konferencijos</li>
  <li id="other" class="hide">Teminiai</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Found a mistake.
I had this earlier in my css file.


`#dropDownBar li{   
  display: block;   
  float: none;   
}`     

But, doesn't specific class override general setting ?

Comment: @NewbieCoder  the selector `#dropDownBar li` has a higher priority/specificity then `.hide` due to the ID selector.

Comment: ahhh, i thought that things are applied as they are written like
`#test{   
margin: auto;                      
margin-top:200px;   
}`
would still work. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly or directly relevant to the question.

But to the reason it was not hiding i would like to add that

**CSS considers specificity.**

"Inline" has the highest priority

"IDs" comes next

Then comes "Classes"

Then comes "HTML TAGS"

```css
body {
  background: red;
}

#body {
  background: pink;
}

.body {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<body id="body" class="body" style="background:blue;">

</body>
```